# If someone is halachically dead and then resuscitated, does his wife need a get to be divorced (is she already a widow)?

Tags: halacha, marriage, death, medicine, resurrection-of-the-dead

If someone is considered halichically dead (apparently this is somewhat of a [dispute](http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/brain.html)), and then he is "brought back" through modern day medical techniques, does his wife need a get to be divorced, or was she already a widow?

Comment: I don't think anyone can resurrect dead people as of current technology...

Comment: @EzraHoerster https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_death          ,                                      http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2315773/Man-died-seventy-minutes-brought-life-heart-attack-doctors-shock-16-times.html

Comment: @EzraHoerster But it has been done so it is a valid question, I guess she is already a widow (since death is a way she goes free) and he probably nothing (since it belongs to his inheritors (this might be the government law also, is he was pronounced dead)). I really enjoy this question +1.

Comment: reb Elchonon Wasserman in Kovets hearot/shiurim treat this

Comment: This question was asked regarding Har Sinai ,I believe the Ben Ish Chai discusses this